# ¿"Se ha explorado" o "Se han explorado"?

Tags: voz-pasiva, concordancia-gramatical, oraciones-pasivas-reflejas, oraciones-impersonales

¿Cuál es el modo correcto de decirlo?

1. En este estudio se **ha** explorado varios métodos.
2. En este estudio se **han** explorado varios métodos.

Recuerdo que cuando estudiaba lengua hace años la profesora decía que
no es correcto decir *habían personas*, sino *había personas*, porque
el sujeto no es *las personas*.

Aquí supongo que pasará algo parecido en la frase propuesta, pues que *varios métodos* no es el sujeto que explora sino el resultado de que alguien haya
explorado.

PD: Al preguntarlo en otro sitio¹ me dicen que del mismo modo hay que
decir *En España **habían** mil romanos*, pero yo pienso que lo correcto
es *En España **había** mil romanos* con *había* en vez de *habían*.

---

1. “¿Había o habían?” https://espanolsinmisterios.blogspot.com.es/2011/07/habia-o-habian.html

Comment: (sobre la PD) Por un momento me has confundido un poco jaja. Creo que lo has escrito justamente al revés. El artículo que enlazas coincide con lo que te dijo tu profesora de lengua.

Comment: Véase [El “se” impersonal y el “se” pasivo](https://blogs.infobae.com/asi-se-escribe/2014/09/07/el-se-impersonal-y-el-se-pasivo/index.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Me gustaría completar la respuesta de Mauricio con un buen artículo que habla de las [vacilaciones en la concordancia](http://hispanoteca.eu/Gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Pasiva%20refleja-Vacilaciones%20en%20la%20concordancia.htm) en este tipo de construcciones y que presenta las posturas de distintos gramáticos, no sólo de la RAE. (Debo aclarar que, a pesar de las virtudes del artículo, tengo serios reparos en cuanto a las perífrasis verbales donde el infinitivo puede interpretarse como sujeto, lo que justifica ampliamente el singular a pesar de que siga un sujeto/objeto plural, como en "Se desea encontrar soluciones".)

Son buenas las recomendaciones que hace la RAE, pero si tienen tiempo de leer el artículo verán que la posición de la Academia es algo simplista. En efecto, no podemos dejar de tener en cuenta que hay casos en que el singular es bastante común o, inclusive, la única alternativa:

- En anuncios, carteles, murales, etc.:

> Se **arregla** paraguas. (También: Se arregla**n**...)

- En ciertas perífrasis verbales:

> Se **tendría que castigar** esos delitos. (También: Se tendría**n**...)
>
> Se **puede / suele / debe** pavimentar las calles. (También: Se puede**n**/suele**n**/debe**n**...)
>
> Se **acabó por adoptar** otras costumbres. (Tal vez la mejor alternativa)
>
> Se **trató de superar** esos inconvenientes. (Tal vez la mejor alternativa)

Esta concordancia con el singular se vuelve más clara si se duplica el objeto directo de la impersonal, colocando el sustantivo al comienzo:

> (En cuanto a) Esos inconvenientes, **se trató** de superarlos.
>
> Actores, se **busca** por doquier.

- Con ciertos verbos donde "semánticamente" hay un sujeto tácito:

> Se **recibió** a los turistas.
>
> Se **aplaudió** a los jugadores.
>
> Se **premió** a los ganadores.
>
> Se **habla** idiomas.
>
> Se **nombrará** a los nuevos ministros.
>
> Se **encontró** diamantes. (Suena más a un descubrimiento minero que "Se encontraron diamantes", donde parece tratarse sólo del hallazgo de objetos.)

- Cuando el objeto está formado por dos sintagmas nominales coordinados:

> Sólo se **oía** el blando batir de las olas y el canto monótono de un grillo.

- Cuando hay distancia entre el verbo y el sintagma nominal en plural:

> Se **veía** a un lado y a otro las mansiones señoriales.

(En estos dos últimos casos, también coincide que los verbos de percepción favorecen la falta de concordancia.)

- Con verbos ditransitivos:

> Se les **da** caramelos a los niños.

- Inclusive puede haber impersonales concordadas, como:

> Estos libros no se vende**n**. (La idea no es que no son vendidos, sino que no están a la venta.)

Comment: Entonces es correcto "sólo se muestra los casos positivos" o "sólo se muestran los casos positivos"

Answer (score 9):

Complementando la respuesta de @FGSUZ, la [RAE](http://www.rae.es/consultas/se-venden-casas-se-buscan-actores-frente-se-busca-los-culpables) habla en esta página al respecto. Para los casos en que se pueda presentar confusión sobre si se trata de oración pasiva refleja u oración impersonal se dice:

> Si el elemento nominal sobre el que recae la acción verbal expresa **cosa**, debe emplearse la construcción de pasiva refleja; por tanto, el verbo ha de ir en plural si este elemento es plural
>
> ej: *Se hacen fotocopias.*

---

> Si el elemento nominal expresa **persona** y **no** va precedido de la preposición **a**, se emplea también la construcción de pasiva refleja:
>
> ej: *Se buscan actores para la película*

---

> Si el elemento nominal expresa **persona** y va precedido de la preposición **a**, debe emplearse la construcción impersonal; por tanto, el verbo irá en singular aunque el elemento nominal sea plural
>
> ej: *Entre los gitanos se respeta mucho a los ancianos*

Por lo tanto, podríamos decir que tu ejemplo es, efectivamente, pasiva refleja porque el elemento nominal (los métodos) sobre el que recae la acción verbal expresa cosa y con esto la forma correcta es "han explorado".

Answer (score 3):

Es una magnífica pregunta, y es "un clásico". La regla es que, si es pasiva refleja, el verbo debe concordar con el sujeto paciente (plural), mientras que si es impersonal, el verbo está en singular.

Bien, ¿y cómo diferenciarlas? Pues es sencillo: construye la pasiva equivalente con el verbo ser. Si es posible, entonces era pasiva, y por tanto el verbo iba en plural.

"se han explorado varios caminos"= "varios caminos fueron explorados". Es equivalente, luego era pasiva refleja → verbo en plural correcto. "Se han explorado varios caminos".

Esto no se puede hacer, en cambio, con las que son realmente impersonales. Por ejemplo "se come bien ahí". No hay forma de convertirla en pasiva.

Comment: OK, gracias.  He actualizado la pregunta con otra relacionada.

Comment: @FGSUZ "Se come bien ahí" no es un ejemplo válido para marcar la diferencia entre la pasiva refleja y la impersonal puesto que en esa oración "comer" es intransitivo.